# Basic question on producing non-overlapping graph nodes in a graph

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

I am plotting a graph which has about 196 nodes.

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 24, 2 -> 24, 20 -> 364, 20 -> 779, 21 -> 130, ...
               378 -> 386, 492 -> 841, 779 -> 783, 839 -> 841}, 
     DirectedEdges -> False, VertexLabeling -> True, 
     Method -> "SpringElectricalEmbedding", 
     PackingMethod -> "ClosestPackingCenter"]
```

However when the output is produced 
it looks like below where many of the nodes are overlapping. How to tell Mathematica
to produce a large picture so that no nodes overlap. True this might not be practical
for very large graphs, but for 196 nodes, I would like no node to overlap another.

[image]

Comment: What if you resize the picture in the front end?

Comment: Yes, that does reduce the problem greatly, but it seems I can resize it only a finite amount with my mouse.

Comment: I was obliquely pointing out why you're seeing the crowdedness. Consider using tinier labels for your nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust the image size using the option `ImageSize->600` or `ImageSize->800`, whatever is needed. You might have missed this option when you look at the help for `GraphPlot` because it is listed indirectly: when you open up the Details section says: `GraphPlot` has the same options as `Graphics`, and under `Graphics` is where you find the `ImageSize` option.

Comment: Thanks. Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Use the Option ImageSize. If ImageSize->Large is not big enough, you can specify the magnification explicitly.